# Anyone know why this href isn't firing the JavaScript in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

Can anyone tell me why this href wouldn't be firing the JavaScript in IE11? It works in all other browsers.

```
<a href="<%# "javascript:checkSelection('UserSImageSelectionByCategory.aspx?PartialPath=" 
               + base64Encode((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PartialPath")) +
               "&var=" + variableName + "', " 
               +DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Height" )+ ", "
                +DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Width" )+")" %>"
             >
```

Comment: try `<a href="#" onclick="checkSelection(...)">`

Comment: as always, how does it get rendered? Looking at serverside code is painful when looking at clientside issues.

Comment: It works in Edge?

Comment: When you "view source" on the web page to see the generated HTML, what is there? Any errors in the console?

Comment: onclick does not work. I haven't tested it in Edge, I will try to do that today. There are no errors being thrown in dev console.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the onclick attribute to call any javascript functions. Href is for hyperlinks to other pages.

```
<a href="#" onclick="<%# "javascript:checkSelection('UserSImageSelectionByCategory.aspx?PartialPath=" 
               + base64Encode((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PartialPath")) +
               "&var=" + variableName + "', " 
               +DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Height" )+ ", "
                +DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Width" )+")" %>"
             >
```

Comment: The thing is that IE isn't picking up the javascript regardless. When using your code, it only picks up the href and goes to the top of the page.